# Visiblity set to Visible if collection contains

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have 2 dependency properties:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Groups), typeof(IEnumerable<string>), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, GroupsChangedCallback));

public IEnumerable<string> Groups
{
    get => (IEnumerable<string>) GetValue(GroupsProperty);
    set => SetValue(GroupsProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibleGroupsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(VisibleGroups), typeof(IEnumerable<string>), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public IEnumerable<string> VisibleGroups
{
    get => (IEnumerable<string>)GetValue(GroupsProperty);
    set => SetValue(GroupsProperty, value);
}
```

I bind ItemsControl to Groups and in DataTemplate I would like to set Visibility to Collapsed if the current group doesn't exist in VisibleGroups.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyControl}}, Path=Groups}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DockPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <!-- here -->
            <Grid  Visibility="{Visible if VisibleGroups contains current group}">

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Is there any easy way to accomplish that or I should create a separate "Group" ViewModel like:

```
public class Group
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public bool IsVisible {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: There is no "easy way" to accomplish this. You need to write some code that determines whether a reference the current item is available in `VisibleGroups`.

Comment: But how would I bind that to `Visibility` then?

Comment: For example using a converter.

Comment: But I can't bind to ConverterParameter to pass current group in ItemsControl. I tried using IMultiValueConverter but I couldn't get it right.

Comment: Bind to `.` and `VisibleGroups`. What did you try?

Comment: But how my converter would access `VisibleGroups`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "easy way" to accomplish this. You need to write some code that determines whether a reference to the current item is available in `VisibleGroups`.

You could for example create an `IMultiValueConverter` that checks whether `values[1]` contains `values[0]`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Visibility>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}">
            <Binding Path="." />
            <Binding Path="VisibleGroups" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyControl}}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Grid.Visibility>
...


</Grid>
```